# Using PDFbox to determine the coordinates of words in a document

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFbox to extract the coordinates of words/strings in a PDF document, and have so far had success determining the position of individual characters. this is the code thus far, from the PDFbox doc:

```
package printtextlocations;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.InvalidPasswordException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class PrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper {

    public PrintTextLocations() throws IOException {
        super.setSortByPosition(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            File input = new File("C:\\path\\to\\PDF.pdf");
            document = PDDocument.load(input);
            if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                try {
                    document.decrypt("");
                } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
                    System.err.println("Error: Document is encrypted with a password.");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
            PrintTextLocations printer = new PrintTextLocations();
            List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
                PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
                System.out.println("Processing page: " + i);
                PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                if (contents != null) {
                    printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param text The text to be processed
     */
    @Override /* this is questionable, not sure if needed... */
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
        System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + ","
                + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale="
                + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
                + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="
                + text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter());
    }
}
```

This produces a series of lines containing the position of each character, including spaces, that looks like this:

```
String[202.5604,41.880127 fs=1.0 xscale=13.98 height=9.68814 space=3.8864403 width=9.324661]P
```

Where 'P' is the character. I have not been able to find a function in PDFbox to find words, and I am not familiar enough with Java to be able to accurately concatenate these characters back into words to search through even though the spaces are also included. Has anyone else been in a similar situation, and if so how did you approach it? I really only need the coordinate of the first character in the word so that parts simplified, but as to how I'm going to match a string against that kind of output is beyond me.

Answer (score 11):

There is no function in PDFBox that allows you to extract words automatically. I'm currently working on extracting data to gather it into blocks and here is my process:

1. I extract all the characters of the document (called glyphs) and store them in a list.
2. I do an analysis of the coordinates of each glyph, looping over the list. If they overlap (if the top of the current glyph is contained between the top and bottom of the preceding/or the bottom of the current glyph is contained between the top and bottom of the preceding one), I add it to the same line.
3. At this point, I have extracted the different lines of the document (be careful, if your document is multi-column, the expression "lines" means all the glyphs that overlap vertically, ie the text of all the columns that have the same vertical coordinates).
4. Then, you can compare the left coordinate of the current glyph to the right coordinate of the preceding one to determine if they belong to the same word or not (the PDFTextStripper class  provides a getSpacingTolerance() method that gives you, based on trials and errors, the value of a "normal" space. If the difference between the right and the left coordinates is lower than this value, both glyphs belong to the same word.

I applied this method to my work and it works good.

Comment: I like this. Is there a specific reason you didn't just look for the space character, use it as a delimiter while building the list? The coord comparison seems like it would be more rigid when provided with things like tabs, etc. but it also seems like it might be 'slower' due to the added char by char calculations. Also, are 'lists' in Java equivalent to arrays or advantageous in some way?

Comment: PDFBox may extract space characters from some documents but in other documents only the letters will be extracted. So, to build a nice app, you should (I think) follow these steps and then if you find a glyph that is equal to " " (space) then you may split the line directly. That could be an idea. I don't really know if lists are more advantageous than arrays, since the concrete implementation of a list may be an ArrayList, I would say that it is somehow comparable. I mainly use lists because of an easy manipulation.

Comment: @user1437888, in my limited experience there aren't any space characters in the PDF documents I've processed.  The text is positioned, and spaces have to be inferred from a space-sized region with no text.  Blecch!

Comment: Concerning the gaps between words... Sometimes there are space characters, sometimes there is merely a jump to the right... It mostly depends on the PDF generating Software.

Comment: basing on personal experience, you'd be better off exploring the original examples that appear in the source code of PDFBox https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi, especially org.apache.pdfbox.examples.util.PrintTextLocations

Answer (score 6):

Based on the original idea here is a version of the text search for PDFBox 2. The code itself is rough, but simple. It should get you started fairly quickly.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import lu.abac.pdfclient.data.PDFTextLocation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;

public class PrintTextLocator extends PDFTextStripper {

    private final Set<PDFTextLocation> locations;

    public PrintTextLocator(PDDocument document, Set<PDFTextLocation> locations) throws IOException {
        super.setSortByPosition(true);
        this.document = document;
        this.locations = locations;
        this.output = new Writer() {
            @Override
            public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            }
            @Override
            public void flush() throws IOException {
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
            }
        };
    }

    public Set<PDFTextLocation> doSearch() throws IOException {

        processPages(document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages());
        return locations;
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        super.writeString(text);

        String searchText = text.toLowerCase();
        for (PDFTextLocation textLoc:locations) {
            int start = searchText.indexOf(textLoc.getText().toLowerCase());
            if (start!=-1) {
                // found
                TextPosition pos = textPositions.get(start);
                textLoc.setFound(true);
                textLoc.setPage(getCurrentPageNo());
                textLoc.setX(pos.getXDirAdj());
                textLoc.setY(pos.getYDirAdj());
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Issue: Keeps only the coords of the last position of a word. But in general it nicely demonstrates the search feature.

Comment: This helped me a lot with few changes

Comment: @MarinosAn please consider adding example what worked for you.

Comment: @sura2k: could you please help me what changes need to do in above to get coordinations ?

Comment: How to get this class PDFTextLocation?

Answer (score 2):

take a look on this, I think it's what you need.

https://jackson-brain.com/using-pdfbox-to-locate-text-coordinates-within-a-pdf-in-java/

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;

public class PrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper {

public static StringBuilder tWord = new StringBuilder();
public static String seek;
public static String[] seekA;
public static List wordList = new ArrayList();
public static boolean is1stChar = true;
public static boolean lineMatch;
public static int pageNo = 1;
public static double lastYVal;

public PrintTextLocations()
        throws IOException {
    super.setSortByPosition(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    PDDocument document = null;
    seekA = args[1].split(",");
    seek = args[1];
    try {
        File input = new File(args[0]);
        document = PDDocument.load(input);
        if (document.isEncrypted()) {
            try {
                document.decrypt("");
            } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
                System.err.println("Error: Document is encrypted with a password.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        PrintTextLocations printer = new PrintTextLocations();
        List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();

            if (contents != null) {
                printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
            }
            pageNo += 1;
        }
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            System.out.println(wordList);
            document.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
    String tChar = text.getCharacter();
    System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + ","
            + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale="
            + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
            + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="
            + text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter());
    String REGEX = "[,.\\[\\](:;!?)/]";
    char c = tChar.charAt(0);
    lineMatch = matchCharLine(text);
    if ((!tChar.matches(REGEX)) && (!Character.isWhitespace(c))) {
        if ((!is1stChar) && (lineMatch == true)) {
            appendChar(tChar);
        } else if (is1stChar == true) {
            setWordCoord(text, tChar);
        }
    } else {
        endWord();
    }
}

protected void appendChar(String tChar) {
    tWord.append(tChar);
    is1stChar = false;
}

protected void setWordCoord(TextPosition text, String tChar) {
    tWord.append("(").append(pageNo).append(")[").append(roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getXDirAdj()))).append(" : ").append(roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getYDirAdj()))).append("] ").append(tChar);
    is1stChar = false;
}

protected void endWord() {
    String newWord = tWord.toString().replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
    String sWord = newWord.substring(newWord.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    if (!"".equals(sWord)) {
        if (Arrays.asList(seekA).contains(sWord)) {
            wordList.add(newWord);
        } else if ("SHOWMETHEMONEY".equals(seek)) {
            wordList.add(newWord);
        }
    }
    tWord.delete(0, tWord.length());
    is1stChar = true;
}

protected boolean matchCharLine(TextPosition text) {
    Double yVal = roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getYDirAdj()));
    if (yVal.doubleValue() == lastYVal) {
        return true;
    }
    lastYVal = yVal.doubleValue();
    endWord();
    return false;
}

protected Double roundVal(Float yVal) {
    DecimalFormat rounded = new DecimalFormat("0.0'0'");
    Double yValDub = new Double(rounded.format(yVal));
    return yValDub;
}
}
```

Dependencies:

> PDFBox,
>   FontBox,
>   Apache Common Logging Interface.

You can run it by typing on command line:

```
javac PrintTextLocations.java 
sudo java PrintTextLocations file.pdf WORD1,WORD2,....
```

the output is similar to:

```
[(1)[190.3 : 286.8] WORD1, (1)[283.3 : 286.8] WORD2, ...]
```

Comment: This code is outdated. Method `processStream(...)` does not exist.

Comment: this code doesn't work with latest versions (pdfbox v2.0.8)

Answer (score 2):

For those who still need assistance, this is what I used in my code and should be useful to start with. It uses PDFBox 2.0.16

```
public class PDFTextLocator extends PDFTextStripper {
    
    private static String key_string;
    private static float x;
    private static float y;
    
    public PDFTextLocator() throws IOException {
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
    }
    
    /**
     * Takes in a PDF Document, phrase to find, and page to search and returns the x,y in float array
     * @param document
     * @param phrase
     * @param page
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static float[] getCoordiantes(PDDocument document, String phrase, int page) throws IOException {
        key_string = phrase;
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextLocator();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        stripper.setStartPage(page);
        stripper.setEndPage(page);
        stripper.writeText(document, new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
        y = document.getPage(page).getMediaBox().getHeight()-y;
        
        return new float[]{x,y};
    }
    
    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.writeString()
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        if(string.contains(key_string)) {
            TextPosition text = textPositions.get(0);
            if(x == -1) {
                x = text.getXDirAdj();
                y = text.getYDirAdj();
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Maven dependency details,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working using the IKVM conversion PDFBox.NET 1.8.9. in C# and .NET.

I finally figured out the character (glyph) coordinates are private to the .NET assembly, but can be accessed using `System.Reflection`.

I posted a full example of getting the coordinates of WORDS and drawing them back on images of PDF's using SVG and HTML here: https://github.com/tsamop/PDF_Interpreter

For the example below you need PDFbox.NET: http://www.squarepdf.net/pdfbox-in-net, and include references to it in your project.

It took me quite a while to figure it out, so I really hope it saves someone else time!!

If you just need to know where to look for the characters & coordinates, a very abridged version would be:

```
    using System;
using System.Reflection;

using org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.apache.pdfbox.util;

  // to test run pdfTest.RunTest(@"C:\temp\test_2.pdf");

class pdfTest
{
    //simple example for getting character (gliph) coordinates out of a pdf doc.
    // a more complete example is here:   https://github.com/tsamop/PDF_Interpreter
    public static void RunTest(string sFilename)
    {
    //probably a better way to get page count, but I cut this out of a bigger project.
    PDDocument oDoc = PDDocument.load(sFilename);
        object[] oPages = oDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().toArray();

        int iPageNo = 0; //1's based!!
        foreach (object oPage in oPages)
        {
            iPageNo++;

            //feed the stripper a page.
            PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            tStripper.setStartPage(iPageNo);
            tStripper.setEndPage(iPageNo);
            tStripper.getText(oDoc);

            //This gets the "charactersByArticle" private object in PDF Box.
            FieldInfo charactersByArticleInfo = typeof(PDFTextStripper).GetField("charactersByArticle", BIndingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            object charactersByArticle = charactersByArticleInfo.GetValue(tStripper);

            object[] aoArticles = (object[])charactersByArticle.GetField("elementData");

            foreach (object oArticle in aoArticles)
            {
                if (oArticle != null)
                {

                    //THE CHARACTERS within the article
                    object[] aoCharacters = (object[])oArticle.GetField("elementData");

                    foreach (object oChar in aoCharacters)
                    {

                        /*properties I caulght using reflection:
                         * endX, endY, font, fontSize, fontSizePt, maxTextHeight, pageHeight, pageWidth, rot, str textPos, unicodCP, widthOfSpace, widths, wordSpacing, x, y
                         * 
                         */
                        if (oChar != null)
                        {
                            //this is a really quick test.  
                            // for a more complete solution that pulls the characters into words and displays the word positions on the page, try this:  https://github.com/tsamop/PDF_Interpreter
                            //the Y's appear to be the bottom of the char?
                            double mfMaxTextHeight = Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("maxTextHeight")); //I think this is the height of the character/word

                            char mcThisChar = oChar.GetField("str").ToString().ToCharArray()[0];
                            double mfX = Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("x"));
                            double mfY = Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("y")) - mfMaxTextHeight;

                            //CALCULATE THE OTHER SIDE OF THE GLIPH
                            double mfWidth0 = ((Single[])oChar.GetField("widths"))[0];
                            double mfXend = mfX + mfWidth0; // Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("endX"));

                            //CALCULATE THE BOTTOM OF THE GLIPH.
                            double mfYend = mfY + mfMaxTextHeight; //  Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("endY"));

                            double mfPageHeight = Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("pageHeight"));
                            double mfPageWidth = Convert.ToDouble(oChar.GetField("pageWidth"));

                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(@"add some stuff to test {0}, {1}, {2}", mcThisChar, mfX, mfY);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}



using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// To deal with the Java interface hiding necessary properties! ~mwr
/// </summary>
public static class GetField_Extension
{
    public static object GetField(this object randomPDFboxObject, string sFieldName)
    {
            FieldInfo itemInfo = randomPDFboxObject.GetType().GetField(sFieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            return itemInfo.GetValue(randomPDFboxObject);
    }

}
```