# How to get (x,y width height )of any given word in pdf using java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to get x,y ,width and height of a given word in pdf. so that later while parsing the same type of file i can fetch value from the co-ordinate itself. How should i get position of a word from PDF using java.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(451, 125,100,1); // i need to get this co-ordate for any particular word
stripper.addRegion("class1", rect);
stripper.extractRegions(pdDocument.getPage(0));
System.out.println("stripper "+stripper.getTextForRegion("class1").trim());
```

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  A PDF defines its text using markup, not rectangles.  You don't actually get an X and Y until the PDF is rendered.

Comment: What library / reader are you using to read the PDF document? Are you just reading it as text or with Apache PDFTextStripper or something else?

Comment: I am using PDFTextStripper to read.

Comment: @Robert *"A PDF defines its text using markup, not rectangles."* - there are tagged pdfs (I assume you mean that by *markup*) but tags are optional in pdfs. Essentially the only required thing in pdfs is that text pieces (or graphics pieces)  are drawn at given coordinates and have fixed dimensions. So in general you *only* have rectangles...

Comment: Have a look at the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example in the source code download. This may come close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could make use of [Apache's `PDFBox` API](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and follow the advice in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11873801/4851565) which is specific to that API to write the code you need.

Comment: it is not giving me width height of the given text. just X,Y.

Comment: What code are you using to get the `x` and `y` coordinates?

Comment: textPosition.getViewQuadrilateral(); // same as in the link u shared.

Comment: AFAICS `textPosition.getViewQuadrilateral()` is not a pdfbox method. I find such a method in quoppa code.