# Get position of text within PDF using iTextSharp 4.1.6

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I've been tasked with creating "Signature" fields within PDF files that we generate. Some of these files are actually various word docs that get pieced together (if they apply) that are then converted to PDF's. Because of this, the position of the "Signature" field could be anywhere (vertically) on the page. We currently have iTextSharp version 4.1.6 and have no intentions of upgrading. I have successfully used this library for many of our other forms when I know the exact position of the field prior to processing.

The route we are thinking of taking is placing some white text where we would want the Signature field located. I would parse the PDF searching for this text and then place a field there. I am by no means a PDF expert and have spent some time looking into the various tokens within the file hoping that there is something I can use but have come up with no answers.

Using this outdated version, is there any way I am able to come up with a solution to finding and placing a field or am I wasting my time?

Comment: *"The route we are thinking of taking is placing some white text where we would want the Signature field located. I would parse the PDF searching for this text and then place a field there."* - A proper API for content parsing and graphics state analysis has not been introduced to iTextSharp before some 5.x version. Thus, with iTextSharp 4.1.6 I cannot recommend taking that route.

Comment: @mkl so is there absolutely nothing to leverage in .NET/itextsharp 4.1.6 to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, you could consider back-porting the parsing code of itext 5.x. But that is not trivial. And if you did that too much like the original, you would become subject to AGPL...

Comment: In short: there is absolutely nothing to leverage in iText 4.1.6 for .NET. Trust mkl on this, wouldn't be the first time that he knows more about iText history from the top of his mind than I do, and I *work* at iText Software.

Comment: I appreciate the replies mkl and @amedee. The route I'm currently pursuing is trying to make sense of the tokens within the file and the x,y coordinates. If we made the assumption that there is a horizontal line below a signature field, I should be able to do some math to figure out how far down the page the line is placed, no?

Comment: So in the end what you want to do is to auto-detect signature "fields"/areas. The whole question imho depends on whether you are in control of the PDF files (and its generation) or you are not and basically any kind of PDF has to be expected. Or a third case: You can not control the generation but you know how the PDFs generally look like. Depeding on the scenario a solution might be possible...

Comment: @Lonzak, in the end I want to be able to determine the coordinates to place an editable "Signature" field on a .pdf when I am unsure of its exact placement vertically on the page. The horizontal position shouldn't change but since there can be more or less pieces that "build" the pdf, it could be further up/down. I more or less have control of the PDF file and its generation. I'm currently struggling understanding the "CTM" and transformations when parsing the PDF tokens.

Comment: Depending on how you put together your PDF another possibility is to add (once (manually) the signature form field to the snippet (you called them pieces) where the signature area is on. Then use iText to concatenate those snippets (with PdfCopyFields) but then the signature is always placed right. I know a customer who has implemented such a solution. I have also extended FOP once to add form fields during generation to avoid your scenario...

Comment: @Lonzak So what actually happens is we have these .doc files that get pieced together with other software to create a single PDF form which also gets flattened in the process.

Comment: Yes we are also doing something like this: We have written a word plugin which uses the word internal PDF conversion functionality. But before we add a special keyword at the signature area (in the *.doc). The keyword is written in a white font so it is not visible. Then during import into our platform we locate the keyword and add a signature field at the location of the keyword...

Comment: @Lonzak so are you attempting to add the keyword to the .doc file, convert the file to pdf, and then locate the keyword while the file is in pdf format? I haven't had the time to work on my token parser lately but I'm hoping to get back into it soon.

Comment: @cookmeup272 Yes exactly. But to locate the keyword coordinates we do not use iText. If you want to use iText the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632541/get-the-exact-stringposition-in-pdf) might help you). Currently still use jpedal but want to switch to pdfbox (then I would look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873801/using-pdfbox-to-determine-the-coordinates-of-words-in-a-document) might help)